# Sending SMS using SMSLib using ProxyServer

Tags: smslib

New to SMSLib.

I checked some samples and docs but did not get any ref/poc wherein I can send SMS with following set-up.

1. I want to send SMS from PC which is connected to internet in office network, where I am using proxy settings to connect to internet.(Basically office PC used in LAN environment)
2. I am not sure how to set the Modem settings in this scenario.
3. What i want - want to test SMS functionality in office environment and would like to send SMS to android based mobile using SMSLib library.
4. I have done SMSLib set-up on my PC and have all the required jars/dlls placed at proper location. So no issues related with set-up. Set-up is on windows platform.
5. I have written sample POC by referring some blogs/SMSLib docs. But as mentioned in points 1 and 2 above, am not getting how to write the code.

Any help/pointers in this regard highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
picku

Comment: share the code and problem what you tried.

Comment: actually whatever I read and checked, I found the USB Modem settings using SerialModemGateway. I am using my organization internet connection using ProxyServer. So am confused how to set that.

Comment: you are following this:http://smslib.org/doc/v4/UsingGSMModems ?

Comment: Yes I am following this link. Actually since I am testing it in my office, I am not able to figure the exact COM port to which I have connected my phone. Also since its organization network I cant explicitly check the port details and all. Hence wanted to check how can I test it in a organization with proper LAN support done with proxy set-up and all. am I missing anything related with the set-up?

Comment: cause of restriction I am not able to check COM port used by mobile connection. I identified ports using CommPortIdentifier and found that COM4,COM5,COM7,COM8,COM9.So I tried using each one of them but all failed with following exception- COM4- org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device

Comment: but all failed with following different exceptions- 
COM4- org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device
COM5- port in use 
COM7- org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device.
COM8- org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device.
COM9- Comm library exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: gnu.io.PortInUseException: Unknown Application